# Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE function to find decimal and special characters

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I am working with table data that contains strings with decimal and back-slash like below:

```
info
1/2.2.2
2/1.1.1
3/1.1.11
```

I need to use a regular expression to replace the data like below:

```
info
1/2.2
2/1.1
3/1.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a (slow) regular expression, use simple (faster) string functions instead:

```sql
SELECT info,
       CASE
       WHEN INSTR(info, '.', 1, 2) > 0
       THEN SUBSTR(info, 1, INSTR(info, '.', 1, 2) - 1)
       ELSE info
       END AS part
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (info) AS
SELECT '1/2.2.2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2/1.1.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3/1.1.11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3/1.1' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| INFO | PART |
| --- | --- |
| 1/2.2.2 | 1/2.2 |
| 2/1.1.1 | 2/1.1 |
| 3/1.1.11 | 3/1.1 |
| 3/1.1 | 3/1.1 |

If you want to update the table then:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET   info = SUBSTR(info, 1, INSTR(info, '.', 1, 2) - 1)
WHERE INSTR(info, '.', 1, 2) > 0
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xptsRsQ9)

Comment: Thanks , Can i replace the data in the same column INFO?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argument, here's a solution using REGEXP_SUBSTR().  REGEXP_SUBSTR() returns NULL if the pattern is not found. Thanks to MT0 for the CTE so I didn't have to type it up :-)

```
WITH table_name(ID, info) AS (
SELECT 1, '1/2.2.2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2/1.1.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '3/1.1.11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '3/1.1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '4/4' FROM DUAL)
SELECT ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(info, '\d/\d\.\d') DATA
from table_name;



        ID DATA    
---------- --------
         1 1/2.2   
         2 2/1.1   
         3 3/1.1   
         4 3/1.1   
         5         

5 rows selected.
```